# around l'Hospital's rule - example

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm looking for a pair $(f,g)$ of $C^{\infty}$ functions such that $f(0)=f'(0)=f''(0)=\dots =0$, the same for $g$, and $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists.

Comment: If $f$ is analytic and $f(0)=f^{(n)}(0)=0, \forall n,$ then $f\equiv 0.$

Comment: right, should be $C^{\infty}$, I'm sorry

Comment: Maybe play with $f(x)=e^{-1/x^2}$ and $g(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: @D.A. $f''(0)=2\ne 0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & if & x= 0 \\ e^{-1/x^2} & if & x\ne 0 \end{cases}$$ and $g(x)=cf(x),$ for some constant $c\ne 0.$ Then, one has that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\dfrac 1c .$$

Comment: How do you define $f(x)/g(x)$ for $x<0$?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Thank you for noticing the mistake.